# wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003 with MessageUI

Tags: ios, messageui

I'm using the MessageUI to send an sms in my app, but when it loads the view, it outputs the following in the log:

```
wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003
```

The code is fairly simply...

```
#define UUID_USER_DEFAULTS_KEY @"UUID" 

#import "RegisterView.h"

@implementation RegisterView

- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result

{
    switch (result) {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Cancelled");
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
            break;
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultSent:

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}




-(IBAction)sendSMS:(id)sender
{
        MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
        if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
        {
            NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

            NSString *deviceID = [defaults objectForKey:UUID_USER_DEFAULTS_KEY];

            NSString *smsBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"add %@", deviceID];

            controller.body = smsBody;
            controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"PRIVATE"];
            controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
            [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
        }
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

I'm not sure if I really need to do anything about the message, since the app is working fine... But I always like to eliminate such things... So, what's causing it?

Comment: Have you done? I have the same question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know , that warning is caused because you are trying to make some animation before the `viewDidAppear` method gets called. It can be your message composer for instance. If you are displaying animated things in `viewDidLoad`
, try to display them in `viewDidAppear` and see if you still get the error.

Cheers!